# A jabber chat client that displays a list of rooms?

Tags: software-recommendation, snow-leopard, jabber, chat

I'm on OS X 10.6.6, and I've tried <strike>Adium and</strike> iChat, but <strike>neither are</strike> iChat isn't capable of showing a list of available rooms anywhere on our company chat server. Does anyone know of a Jabber chat client that can? Thanks!

**Update**: See my answer at the bottom of the page ;)

Yes **Adium** can!

Comment: @Dori thanks for the retag! Hopefully, someone will know the answer to this soon. I hope Psi isn't the only option.  For whatever reason it didn't work, and my IT guy couldn't confirm that the server wasn't configured correctly as @VxJasonxV suggested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the answer to my question *is* to use **Adium**. A **lucky discovery**: I was about to disconnect my chat account using the File menu, but when I moused over the text "Disconnect: ...", a context menu appeared as one might expect. However, I had never clicked the item labeled **Discovery Browser**. Under the server's "Public Chatrooms" I found a list with the JID of all the active chat rooms.

Comment: I don't see the "Public Chatrooms" option.

Comment: @SteveMoser You won't see "Public Chatrooms" if you're using the google chat service.  I no longer use Adium with public chatrooms, because I no longer work at a job that has public chatrooms.  I apologize if my answer didn't apply to your situation.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

The only client I've come across that does this is [Psi](http://psi.im/). There's a "Service Discovery" item in the menus, and browsing the conference/muc bridge interface SHOULD list all the registered rooms.

[image: Service Discovery Window for My XMPP Server]

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me. Looks like it hasn't been an actively developed piece of software for a couple of years either.

Comment: This is unfortunately true. The actual active Psi developers switched Swift, but it's supposed to be "simple" and I believe it won't have the option you seek.

Comment: If Psi did not work (and the "Automatically Get Info" box was checked at the bottom, it is the default), I suspect your server does not allow node browsing. I posted a screenshot of my Jabber Server, and you'll see that the rooms that actually have people in it are listed.